# How can I put a gradient color on a button text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

So, i have this bootstrap button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Some text</button>
```

and I want to make the button text ("Some text") to have this gradient:

```
linear-gradient(to bottom right, #67b26f, #4ca2cd);
```

I tried to set the color property to add gradient using CSS, but not working.

Is there a way using CSS to give that text a gradient color?

Thank you and have a good day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this one**

```css
button {
 font-size: 72px;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Some text</button>
```

> **UPDATE**
>
> If you want to add background-color for button then you can use :after
>   content.

**LIke this :**

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

/* for adding bg-color for btn */
button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Some text</button>
```

Comment: How can you give the button a background color other than white? For example, blue?

Comment: @NicScozzaro, I updated my answer . Please check. I added :after content for bg-color .

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the gradient as the background-image and then set the text color to transparent and then use the -webkit-background-clip property to set it to text. Try this:

```
.gradient-text {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #67b26f, #4ca2cd);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
}
```

now just add the gradient-text class to the button and make sure it comes after the bootstrap styles :)